# User input error when using python's socket library

Tags: python, sockets, runtime-error

So I am trying to take user input for the IP address that I want the server to connect to however anytime I use my user input the server fails to connect with the error *[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo* *failed*

This is the original code that does not work

```
    IP = raw_input('Connect to IP:')
    IP2 = '127.0.0.1'
    try:
        server.connect((IP, PORT))
```

However if I then attempt to use IP2 it works perfectly I have no idea why they would not be the same if I type in 127.0.0.1 on my own.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just test `IP == IP2` after entry.  If they are different, you are doing something weird.  `raw_input` (which only exists in Python 2...upgrade!!) returns a string, and I get an exact match of typing IP vs. use IP2, so you have to show **exactly** what you are doing to get more help.

Comment: It says they are different when I test them also what would I use in Python3?

Comment: Upgrading my python version fixed it perfectly.

Comment: What was different about them?  I really don't know how they would be different unless you show the *exact* code to reproduce the issue.  At least `print(repr(IP),repr(IP2))` when it fails and show the result.

Comment: They appeared to be the same but for some reason python registered them differently

Answer (score -1):

when you use `try` you need to add `except` after it

```
try:
    server.connect((IP, PORT))
except:
    pass
```